# Updating Stripe customer address and NOT card info

Tags: javascript, jquery, credit-card, stripe-payments

Is it possible to just update a customer's stored address on Stripe and not the card as well? Reason I am asking is the way I have it now, the customer can update their info, but it requires their card to be entered as well even if it is just a city change.

I'm using the following to create a token and update the customer's info

```
$("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
    // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $('#stripe-submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

    // combine first & last name
    var fullname = $('[name="first-name"]').val() + " " + $('[name="last-name"]').val();

    // send the card details to Stripe
    Stripe.createToken({
        number: $('.card-number').val(),
        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('.card-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('.card-year').val(),
        name: fullname,
        address_line1: $('[name="address"]').val(),
        address_city: $('[name="city"]').val(),
        address_state: $('[name="state"]').val(),
        address_zip: $('[name="zip"]').val(),
        address_country: $('[name="country"]').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);

    // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
});
```

Is there something like an updateToken I could use? So I could change only certain values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been available for a while now:

- Announcement https://stripe.com/blog/multiple-cards
- Api docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_card

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, no. To update any property of the card you'll need to re-collect the full card details from the customer.

Comment: Is this doc'd somewhere?  It's just sooo hard to believe (though I couldn't determine a way in which to do so, either).

Comment: I work for Stripe, so I can confirm that it's not possible to update properties a card.

Comment: Thanks Brian - it would be *extremely helpful* if this functionality were available. ;)

Comment: @brian is there any way to update all the card details via js?  From what I can tell you have to create a new card and add it to a customer, and then delete the old card...

Comment: @brian not sure if you still work at Stripe, but is this possible at all now?